Structure of well-ordered commutative monoids
Let $(M,+)$ be a commutative monoid.  Let $<$ be a well-ordering on $M$, where

$\forall a\in M,\ 0\leq a$
$\forall a,b,c\in M,\ a<b\Rightarrow a+c<b+c$

The first condition means $M$ will be part of the positive cone in its Grothendieck group (after extending the ordering to the group in the obvious way).
It is well-known that the second condition is equivalent over commutative semigroups to the conjunction of cancellativity and torsion-freeness (where torsion-freeness is understood in the commutative semigroup sense, that if $s^n=t^n$ for some integer $n\geq 1$, then $s=t$).
Taken together, the two conditions tell us that this well-ordering extends the usual algebraic pre-ordering on monoids given by: $a\preceq b$ exactly when $\exists c,\ a+c=b$.
My question regards any known structure theorems for this situation, even if we restrict ourselves to considering the case when $M$ is countable.  Specifically, I'm wondering what can be said if $(M,<)$ is not Archimedean.
The fact that $<$ is a well-ordering significantly limits possible structure.  We also know that $M$ embeds in a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space (although I'm not sure that $<$ extends to that vector space).
(By the way, I'm also interested in the case when $<$ is merely a well-founded partial ordering.)

Well-orderedness does not restrict the structure that much, actually. In particular, finitely generated linearly ordered nonnegative commutative monoids are automatically well ordered due to Dickson’s lemma (more generally, a finitely generated nonnegative partially ordered commutative monoid is wpo).

For an example that things may go nasty, Let $G$ be an ordered abelian group generated by elements ${x_n:n\in\mathbb Z}$ such that $x_{n+1}>mx_n$ for all integer $m$, and let $M$ be the submonoid generated by ${x_n,x_n+x_{-n}:n\ge0}$. Then $M$ is well ordered, but its Grothendieck group is $G$, which has an infinite descending chain of archimedean classes. By tinkering with the construction a bit, one can even get a densely ordered set of archimedean classes.

@EmilJeřábek Thanks for that example.  I recently came up with a slightly different nastiness, so I'm thinking that there may not be any pretty structure theorem.
